# Display pdf files that contain a specific key-word

Tags: php, file, pdf, search, full-text-search

I am trying to develop a search tool that  would search the words inside all of the PDFs, and the results would list all of the PDFs that contain the word or term inside. I am a complete beginner and have no idea how it goes . I tried searching over internet and got one source ie https://github.com/skfaisal93/AnyWhereInFiles

The above project link is working fine with txt,css and php files but not working with pdf extensions.

any idea or solutions will be good . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PDF2Text Class](https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/31030.html) to convert the pdf into text and, after that, search through the text about your words. I strongly suggest for better performance you do that routine when store the pdfs into your system, saving in a database with 2 tables, 1 with the pdfs names and other (1-N) with the text inside it to the future searchs. TL;DR What you need it's to [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)/extract the file, store him and do the full-text-search with some commands from the db or backend.

With the PDF2Text Class you can do:

```
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('youfile.pdf'); 
$a->decodePDF();
//use the db you want
sql = "insert into TABLEPDF (name, content) VALUES ('youfile', $a->output())";
```

After that, when the user put the keywords to search into your input, it's just search into your db, listing after search (if the num_rows > 0) the pdfs that contain that keywords:

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM TABLEPDF where content like '%$keyword%';
```

You can use OCR classes too, improving the files accepted by the system:
http://phpocr.sourceforge.net/
https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php

Comment: This is  exactly the answer i was looking for . Thanks for the solution